# Dataframe taking lot of time to load data from sql query

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing an issue wherein I am getting database records in a data frame. But the reading of data from the database itself is taking a lot of time for 400000 records in the result set of the query.

Below is the read method I am using.

```
def read_data(self, query, chunk_size=10000000, auto_close_connection=False):
    """
    Retrieves the query result from the database into a dataframe. Returns an empty dataframe if no records found.

    :param query: The query string to fire to the database
    :param chunksize: Number of records to be fetched at a time from the database. Default value is 1 Crore.
    :param auto_close_connection: Boolean value to specify whether or not to close the engine immediately after the retriving the data. Default value is False. If kept as False, make sure to call close_engine() after use.
    :return: Dataframe containing the entire resultset of the query
    """
    iteration_count = 0
    data_frame = None
    try:
        print("Started reading data from DB...")
        for chunk in pan.read_sql(query, self.engine, chunksize=chunk_size):
            iteration_count += 1
            if iteration_count == 1:
                data_frame = chunk
            else:
                data_frame = pan.concat([data_frame, chunk], axis=0)
            print("Read chunk from database: iteration - %d" % (iteration_count))
        if iteration_count == 0:  # So that an empty dataframe with columns is created if 0 rows are returned
            data_frame = pan.read_sql(query, self.engine)
        print("Finished reading data from DB")
        return data_frame
    finally:
        if auto_close_connection:
            self.close_engine()

    def get_db_records_in_data_frame(engine, query):
        data_df = engine.read_data(query)
        data_df.fillna("", inplace=True)
        return data_df
```

I am calling get_db_records_in_data_frame in my class as

```
perfIdsSOIOneThreeHundred = get_db_records_in_data_frame(rds_db_conn,select_queries['select_performance_ids_from_BoB'])
```

The code waits after the line Started reading data from DB... for nearly 20 min. Can anyone help me in this? Anything to do with the chunk size?

Comment: Did you try with lower `chunk_size`? What is your query?

Comment: It's just a select query. I cannot share the query with you as it is confidential. An example of query is select sr.eid,sr.avfrom refdata.vendordata vpd
inner join refdata.se_raw sr on vpd.eid = sr.eid 
where sr.attribute_id =54 and sr.attribute_value in ('1','3','100')

Comment: Please try to avoid using words *lakh* and *crore*, since they are not globally understood.